# Adding spacy pre-trained model download to a yml file

Tags: python-3.x, yaml, spacy

I am writing a python code which is dependent on spaCy and its pre-trained models. For this code I would like to create a yml file to install all dependencies. So far it looks like this:

```
name: my_pkg
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - anaconda
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - pandas
  - numpy
  - spacy
```

However in order to make spacy up and running I also need to download the pre-trained models. Based on the spacy website I should use `python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm` command to download the model, but I don't know how to add this command to the yml file. I'm wondering if someone could help me to fix the yml in a way that it automatically download the spacy pre-trained models

Comment: YAML is just data. What tool do you use to process this YAML file?

Comment: @flyx, sorry I had to mention this. But I am going to create an isolated  python environment using the yml file to run my code

Answer (score 2):

You can find what models are downloadable with `conda`:

`conda search *en_core_web_md*`

---

```
# Name                       Version           Build  Channel     
spacy-model-en_core_web_md           2.0.0  py27hdea317b_0  conda-forge
spacy-model-en_core_web_md           2.1.0    pyhdea317b_0  conda-forge
spacy-model-en_core_web_md           2.2.0            py_0  conda-forge
spacy-model-en_core_web_md           2.2.0    pyhdea317b_0  conda-forge
spacy-model-en_core_web_md           2.2.5            py_0  conda-forge
spacy-model-en_core_web_md           2.3.0    pyh9f0ad1d_0  conda-forge  
spacy-model-en_core_web_md           2.3.1    pyh9f0ad1d_0  conda-forge
```

Then for your yml file you can try:

```
name: my_pkg
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - anaconda
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - pandas
  - numpy
  - spacy
  - spacy-model-en_core_web_md==2.3.1
```

Comment: @amiref Does it answer your question? Was it helpful? Please consider https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers